# How do I check whether the string $_GET["s"] has ++++ in it?

Tags: php, wordpress

I can also call  $_GET["s"] with get_search_query() which outputs a string.

I tried a lot of codes that were supposed to work but none did. Most give true whatever I do. Isn't there a simple way to do this? Thanks

Comment: Will [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) work for you?

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted some of the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you mean the literal string "++++"...

```
if (strpos($_GET['s'], '++++') !== false) {
    // there, do something
} else {
    // not there, do something else
}
```

Reference: http://php.net/strpos

Answer (score 1):

```
if( strpos( $_GET['s'], '++++' ) !== false ) {
    // has
} else {
    // doesn't have
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure quite what's troubling you, or if I'm misunderstanding the question, but surely [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) is what you need:

```
if (strpos($_GET["s"],'++++') !=== false) {
   // the string '++++' was found
}
```

---

**Edited** to fix 'strpos' (nee 'strpoa') typo...oops! With thanks @Jonah Bron =)

Comment: Oops, typo.  `strpos`, not `strpoa` ;)